# Why Hadoop inside Azure

Tags: azure

I am new to azure development. I have to select database in azure to store big data. So i have to finalize  data storage now.

Strongly like to understand why hadoop ( Non Microsoft ) in side azure ? ( I hope some strong reasons will be )

1) Available Azure storage (ex blobs etc ) can not perform like hadoop ?

2) Can not achieve something in azure but can achieve in hadoop ?

3) Perfoemance ?

like this lots of question coming to me, Please provide clear ideas on  this.

Regards,

Prabhu.R

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, you have [HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/) which the Microsoft implementation of Hadoop in Azure.

1. HDInsight can use Azure Storage (Blob) like an HDFS storage
2. Hadoop and all his eco-system (scoop, storm, etc...) can do the job, Azure is just an hosting environment. Microsoft doesn't decide to create new tools because tools like this works fine. That is a good point for Azure Platform, it's not only .Net feature & framework.
3. Like on-premise, if you scale to multiple Large Instance, you will get good performance. Considering that you choose the same infrastructure, there is no reason that performance will be smaller.

Hope this help